# java - Object cannot be resolved to variable

Tags: java, object, setter

I'm trying to write a very simple, little java program but I'm already stuck at setting the object name.
I have 2 classes, first is Starter:

```
public class Starter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Family tester = new Family();
        tester.setName(testers);        
    }
}
```

If i'm right I create a Family object called tester, then I use the setName method for giving the family a name.
The Family class lookes like this:

```
public class Family{
    String Name;

    public void setName(String name){
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

But in the starter class at the tester.setName I get this error: tester cannot be resolved to a variable.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
tester.setName(testers);
```

with

```
tester.setName("testers");
```

As your Family class's `setName()` method takes a `String` object and `String` needs to be created either as above example or as below example:

```
String testers = new String("testers");
//and then you can use above String object as in your code snippet (as follows)
tester.setName(testers);
```

Comment: This is just... ARRWWGG I am so stupid! I tried the single quotations  but that didn't helped so Í thought java would make up that it is a string. Tranks a lot!

Comment: Yeah in Java it's useful to throw single quotes out the window when you're thinking about Strings. In case you didn't figure it out single quotes are to denote the primitive `char` type.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other programming languages, in Java Strings must be enclosed in double quotes.

Single quotes are used for chars, a primitive data type.

You can change your code within;

tester.setName("testers");

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistake in the setName():

```
public class Starter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Family tester = new Family();
//      tester.setName(testers);
//      variable testers is not defined, you means set the name to "testers"? Try this:
        tester.setName("testers");
    }
}
```